Auto-save is enabled at 2 minute intervals, but only auto-saves every 30 minutes
Does anyone know why Blender wouldn't auto-save at the given time interval? I couldn't recover about half an hour's work.

How do you know how often it saves? I mean how exactly did you determine that? Did you test it other that that one instance where you lost the work? It doesn't save unmodified files. What's the location of your autosaves? Is it possible they get deleted somehow? What's the OS you use? Also, what happened? Did Blender crash or was it the whole computer that turned off/restarted?

PSA : Modal operators disable the autosave feature. Make sure none of the addons you use make use of modal operators. Cheers
